# jruby on rails missing mysql-adapter

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I am deploying a JRuy on Rails app to a Tomcat instance and get the following error when I try to pull up the app in a  Web browser:

> INFO: /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Sep 01
>   12:27:30 -0400 2010   Status: 500
>   Internal Server Error   no such file
>   to load -- file:/C:/Tomcat
>   6.0/webapps/VamWebDashboard/WEB-INF/lib/gems.jar!/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.7-java/lib/jdbc_adapter/../active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter

Interesting thing is that when I run the app in Aptana's Webrick server it works just fine.

I am using warbler to package the app into a war.

Anyone run into this issue before? or have any suggestions?

Not sure why app in tomcat is using 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter' when in database.yml i have:

> adapter: jdbcmysql

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

commented out

```
#   config.features = %w(gemjar)
```

in config/warble.rb